# How to stop docker container from starting if app initialization has failed?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We have a flask service application which connects to a mysql database for data. This flask app is server via gunicorn in a docker container. We are using docker-compose for the same.

When the application starts we make the connection to the database. If the connection to the database fails (3 attempts) the application fails to initialize and exits. But am noticing that the container starts. How can i cause the container to fail to start as well when my app fails to start?

Comment: If the main process in a container exits, the container will exit as well.  Can you add enough of your application and deployment framework (`docker-compose.yml`, any wrapper entrypoint scripts involved) to make a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to tell `docker-compose` that you want all containers to stop execution upon exit of your main service. This is done using `--abort-on-container-exit` command line argument. Lets say if you have 2 services:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    ...
  flask:
    ...
```

then command line will look something like:

```
docker-compose up --exit-code-from flask --abort-on-container-exit
```

Thus telling your `flask` service is main and you don't want to continue when it exits.

Second, you configure your `flask` main process (`PID 1`) to exit (preferably with non-zero exit code) if it fails to connect to database. Thats' it.

Answer (score 0):

use `restart:no`
there are 3 options for restart policy.

```
- restart: no
- restart: always
- restart: on-failure
```

Answer (score 0):

If it really starts (not in permanent restarting), try add `trap 'exit' ERR` in top of your entrypoint's script.